# DSolve versus DSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations, language-design

I've just discovered the new command [`DSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolveValue.html) in Mathematica 10. Is this new command now the preferred instead of [`DSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html)? Is it the better command to teach to students? Same question for [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue.html), [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue.html)?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: This seems to be primarily opinion-based.  Each has their uses, depending on the ways in which you wish to use their output.  WRI added them because users wanted all the various ways of getting the output prepackaged, or so they said at WTC this year.  FWIW, for my uses, I prefer `DSolve`, `NDSolve`, and `ParametricNDSolveValue`.

Comment: At first I thought about `ParametricNDSolveValue`: "this is the most absurd function; why would anyone bother to implement this trivial wrapper around `ParametricNDSolve`?". But then I used it, and it seemed at least somewhat worthwhile. So, they definitely have their uses, although I wouldn't say they're in any sense "preferred"--they're just wrappers, provided for your convenience. The preference is up to you.